# Registering @fastify/middie generates error

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I am trying to integrate Fastify into a little package I am building. One of the requirements of this package is to be able to use Middleware (via @fastify/middie). However, when I go through the necessary steps to register the middie plugin, I get the following error from my Editor:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FastifyMiddie' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>'.
      Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
        Property 'use' is missing in type 'FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProvider>' but required in type 'FastifyInstance<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, FastifyLoggerInstance>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginAsync<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FastifyMiddie' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginAsync<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger> | FastifyPluginAsync<...> | Promise<...> | Promise<...>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'FastifyMiddie' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger> | FastifyPluginAsync<...> | Promise<...> | Promise<...>'.
      Type 'FastifyMiddie' is not assignable to type 'FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMiddieOptions, Server, FastifyTypeProvider, FastifyBaseLogger>'.
```

I have included the relevant code below. The important parts here are the import of @fastify/middie at line 4. The way Fastify is instantiated in the constructor. And, following line from the _setupServer() function:

```
this._server.register(FastifyMiddie, {
                hook: 'preHandle'
            });
```

Particularly, the error seems to suggest the @fastiffy/middie package doesn't implement the `use()` method.

Now, I attempted to switch this dependency with the @fastify/express plugin, thinking it was maybe a bug with the Middie package. But, I get the same error. So, my guess is it has to be an error with how I am registering the middie plugin.

Any suggestions about what I need to change?

Code Snippet

```
import Fastify, { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import Cors from '@fastify/cors';
import Static from '@fastify/static';
import FastifyMiddie from '@fastify/middie';

/**
 * HttpServer
 * 
 * The Solidus HttpServer.
 */
export class HttpServer implements HttpServerInterface {

    private readonly _rootComponent: Component;
    private readonly _server: FastifyInstance;
    private readonly _middleware: Middleware[];
    private readonly _config: Configuration;
    private readonly _corsOptions?: CorsOptions

    constructor(
        root: Component,
        config: Configuration,
        middleware: Middleware[] = [],
        cors: CorsOptions|undefined = undefined
    ) {
        this._rootComponent = root;
        this._middleware = middleware;
        this._config = resolveConfig(config);
        this._corsOptions = cors;
        this._server = Fastify({
            logger: true
        });
        this._setupServer();
    }

    // other stuff here....

    /**
     * _setupServer()
     * 
     * _setupServer() sets up the HttpServer.
     */

    private _setupServer(): void {
        // register middleware if it is defined
        if (this._middleware.length > 0) {
             // register middleware.

            // this line is throwing the error.
            this._server.register(FastifyMiddie, {
                hook: 'preHandle'
            });
            this._middleware.forEach(middleware => this._server.use(middleware));
        }

        // set up cors if it is enabled.
        if (this._corsOptions) {
            this._server.register(Cors, {
                // cors settings.
                allowedHeaders: this._corsOptions?.allowHeaders,
                credentials: this._corsOptions.credentials,
                exposedHeaders: this._corsOptions.exposeHeaders,
                hideOptionsRoute: this._corsOptions.hideOptionsRoute,
                maxAge: this._corsOptions.maxAge,
                methods: this._corsOptions.methods,
                optionsSuccessStatus: this._corsOptions.optionsSuccessStatus,
                origin: this._corsOptions.origin,
                preflight: this._corsOptions.preflight,
                preflightContinue: this._corsOptions.preflightContinue,
                strictPreflight: this._corsOptions.strictPreflight
            });
        }

        // register public path.
        this._server.register(Static, {
            root: join(process.cwd(), '/dist/public'),
        });

        // register the error handler
        this._server.setErrorHandler((error, req, res) => {
            this._server.log.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        });

        // register the main route.
        this._server.get('*', async (req, res) => {
            const tags: TagDescription[] = []
            const App = this._configureRootComponent(this._rootComponent, req.url, req.ip, tags);

            if (this._config.ssr! === 'stream') {
                renderToStream(() => <App />).pipe(res.raw);
            }
            else {
                let page: string;

                try {
                    if (this._config.ssr! === 'async') {
                        page = await renderToStringAsync(() => <App />);
                    }
                    else {
                        page = renderToString(() => <App />);
                    }
                    res
                        .status(200)
                        .header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                        .send(this._configureResponse(page, tags));
                }
                catch (e) {
                    this._server.log.error((e as Error).message);
                    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mismatched interface from version incompatibility between the libraries. See this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/11265#issuecomment-1465461720) for example.

The `fastify` library probably introduced a breaking change, and the `@fastify/middie` didn't update their source in time.

You have to find a `fastify` version that `@fastify/middie` is compatible.

I've tested with these versions and it seems to work ok:

```
    "@fastify/middie": "^8.3.0",
    "fastify": "^4.25.1"
```